# How to add Activity on Fragment Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, fragment

This is a sample of my code, I want make a new application, and I want copy code from my previous project, but I get an error.

HomeFragment.java (from Sliding Menu)

```
package com.example.sia;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup; 

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

Account.java

```
package com.example.sia2;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Account extends Activity {

Button logout;
SessionManager session;
TextView status;
JSONArray contacts = null;
String nim, name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_account);

    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "User Login Status: " + session.isLoggedIn(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

    session.checkLogin();

    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

    name = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME);
    // id = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID);

    TextView status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
    status.setText(Html.fromHtml("Welcome,<b>" + name + "</b>  "));

    logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);

    logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            session.logoutUser();
            finish();
        }
    });
}

}
```

I combine the code

```
package com.example.sia;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import com.example.sia.R;
import com.example.sia.SessionManager;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

Button logout;
SessionManager session;
TextView status;
JSONArray contacts = null;
String nim, name;

public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
/**public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_account);**/

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);



    session = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"User Login Status: " + session.isLoggedIn(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    session.checkLogin();

    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

    name = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME);
    // id = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID);

    TextView status = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.status);
    status.setText(Html.fromHtml("Welcome,<b>" + name + "</b>  "));

    logout = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.logout);

    logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            session.logoutUser();
            getActivity().finish();
        }

    });
    return rootView;  
}  


}    
/*public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    return rootView;
}*/
```

I can launch the application, but when I open `fragment_home.xml`, it is not responding

Thank you

Comment: Please post what you have tried and please format the post better (indentation).

Comment: I don't suppose you'd consider putting the actual error here?  Of course not.  That would make it to easy...

Answer (score 0):

Before you go merging you should probably know how a Fragment is composed versus an activity. (You have a sample `HomeFragment.java`!)

1. There is no `setContentView` method because you inflate your layout by overriding the `onCreateView` method.
2. There is no `findViewById` method, instead you find those references within `onCreateView` by calling `findViewById` on the `View` you inflated.
3. `getApplicationContext()` can be replaced by `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

Please read up on Fragments here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

solved :) Thank U

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
....
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
.....
.....
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
}
```